# Selecting same coloured elements using jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to make query a web page based on a particular color. i'm currentlyt using the following page http://api.jquery.com/ .Now suppose i want to select all the elements which are blue in color ,What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out the matched element with given criteria.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XDq98/)**

```
redColored = $('#parentid').children().filter(function(){ 
    if(this.style.color == 'red')
      return $(this);
})
```